# Another OpenCV / cvBlob and Architecture Issue

Tags: c++, macos, opencv

Although this has been asked before, by a number of people, this is not the basic install question (while the answer may be simple).

OK, I am running two install of OpenCV side-by-side (2.3.1 and the latest 2.4) but I primarily use 2.3.1.

So, I have had cvBlob working fine before (on the same machine) but I came around to doing some reinstall. Anywho, I have build OpenCV successfully and I have made the change from the CvBlob project site to include the [OpenCV library in the CMakeLists.txt](http://code.google.com/p/cvblob/wiki/HowToInstall)

To make sure that OpenCV was fine, I have run and re-run make and make install to ensure it is in the usr/local/include directory. Test applications using OpenCV work fine and using`file opencv_library.dylib` shows that the opencv libs are 64 bit.

On to the crux of the problem, I run `cmake .` from the root of the cvblob dir and all comes back fine. `make` and then `sudo make install` is run and I am told that all went well. Again, `file` shows that libcvblob is a 64 bit library, although I am not using it.

I go to a c++ program that uses both opencv and cvblob, with absolute paths to opencv.hpp and cvblob.h as includes.

Then, this:

`Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_cvLabel", referenced from:
      _main in cchIl24a.o
  "_cvFilterByArea", referenced from:
      _main in cchIl24a.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status`

Not sure what has gone wrong, aside from the obvious, but it should have linked to the opencv libs and I cannot see where I may have gone wrong. Has anybody got any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

All those questions and problems regarding cvBlobLib are from the old days, when OpenCV did not have a blob tracker, and someone wrote it, and put on the web. For some reason, it became very popular.

But that was many years ago.

Now you can simply use the included [SampleBlobDetector](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/features2d/doc/common_interfaces_of_feature_detectors.html?highlight=blob#SimpleBlobDetector%20%3a%20public%20FeatureDetector) bundled with opencv, with no hassle. It is more mature, robust, and has more features. And you do not have to worry about include/link problems.

Comment: I appreciate the response and I have used the Sample Blob Detector but I have not found it to be a match in performance to cvBlob. Thanks anyway, though!